# Mockito and HttpServletResponse - write output to textfile

Tags: java, unit-testing, servlets, mocking, mockito

I want to test my servlet using mockito. I also want to know what the server output is. So if the servlet writes something out like this:

```
HttpServletResponse.getWriter().println("xyz");
```

I want to write it to a textfile instead. I created the mock for the HttpServletResponse and tell Mockito it should return my custom PrintWriter if HttpServletResponse.getWriter() is called:

```
HttpServletResponse resp = mock(HttpServletResponse.class);
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("somefile.txt");
when(resp.getWriter()).thenReturn(writer);
```

The textfile is generated, but it is empty. How can I get this working?

**Edit:**

@Jonathan: Thats actually true, mocking the writer as well is a much cleaner solution. Solved it like that

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter pw  =new PrintWriter(sw);

when(resp.getWriter()).thenReturn(pw);
```

Then I can just check the content of the StringWriter and does not have to deal with files at all.

Comment: Nice. I hadn't considered the use of a `StringWriter`.

Comment: http://blog.khubla.com/java/servlet-mocking-with-mockito another way

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To see any output with the `PrintWriter` you need to `close()` or `flush()` it.

Alternatively you can create the [`PrintWriter` with the `autoFlush` parameter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#PrintWriter-java.io.Writer-boolean-), e.g.:

```
final FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("somefile.txt");
final PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fos, true); // <-- autoFlush
```

This will write to the file when `println`, `printf` or `format` is invoked.

I would say closing the `PrintWriter` is preferable.

***Aside:***

Have you considered mocking the `Writer`? You could avoid writing to a file and verify the expected calls instead, e.g.:

```
verify(writer).println("xyz");
```

Answer (score 9):

If you happen to be using Spring then it has a MockHttpServletResponse class.

```
@Test
public void myTest() {
    MockHttpServletResponse response = new MockHttpServletResponse();
    // Do test stuff here
    // Verify what was written to the response using MockHttpServletResponse's methods
    response.getContentAsString();
    response.getContentAsByteArray();
    response.getContentLength();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I know this is a late answer, but I just figured out a way to do this (without having to write to a file). We could use `org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse`.